# How do I most efficiently check the unique char?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Can some one help me out how can I check the unique char with small changes in my existing code. your response would be appreciated.

```
public class UniqueStringCheck {
    public boolean checkUniqueString(String inputString){
        String parseString = inputString.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]","");
        int StringLength = parseString.length();

        char[] sequenceOfString= parseString.toCharArray();
        if(StringLength>0){
            if(sequenceOfString.equals("[^A-Za-z0-9]")){
                System.out.println("No unique char!");
                return false;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Contains Unique char");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify: 1) what do you mean by "unique" String? 2) What's wrong with the code you've posted (other than not being well formatted)?

Comment: Formatting corrected.

Comment: does this code even compile?

Comment: OK, maybe I'm slow, but I still have no idea of what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels me even slower tonite... we also got a full fledged solution below and I still don't get what this unique string is about

Comment: I am still not sure what he wishes to achieve? Is he looking for a string which isn't alphanumeric or something else?

Comment: Which is not alphabetic

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to handle this, if I'm interpreting the question correctly (a string made up of unique characters). Here's four possible solutions of varying efficiencies. Modify as you see fit.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class IsUnique {

    /*With use of additional data structures
      Time complexity can be argued to be O(1) because the for-loop will never
      run longer than the size of the char-set (128, 256, or whatever UTF-8 is).
      Otherwise, time complexity is O(n), where n is the size of the input string.
      Space Complexity is O(1).
     */
    public boolean isUnique(String s) {
        //ExASCII = 256. Standard ASCII = 128. UTF-8 = ???
        if (s.length() > 256) {
            return false;
        }
        Set<Character> letterSet = new HashSet<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (!letterSet.contains(c)) {
                letterSet.add(c);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*Without the use of additional data structures
      Uses int as a bit mask.
      Assumption: letters a-z, lowercase only
      Time complexity, again, can be argued to be O(1) for the same reasons.
      If that argument is not accepted, O(n), where n is the size of the input
      string.
      Space Complexity: O(1), but it uses a smaller amount of space than the
      previous solution.
     */
    public boolean isUniqueWithoutSet(String s) {
        int check = 0;
        if (s.length() > 26) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            int val = s.charAt(i) - 'a';
            val = 1 << val;
            if ((check & val) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            check |= val;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*Without the use of additonal data structures.
      Sorts the underlying character array of the string, iterates through it and
      compares adjacent characters.
      Time complexity: O(nlogn). Arguably, O(n^2) if the java quick-sort hits its
      worst-case time (highly unlikely).
      Space complexity: Arguably, O(1), because the largest the array will ever be
      is the size of the character set. Otherwise, O(n), where n is the size of
      the input string.
     */
    public boolean badSolution(String s) {
        if (s.length() > 26) {
            return false;
        }
        char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
        java.util.Arrays.sort(charArray);

        for (int i = 0, j = i + 1; i < charArray.length - 1; i++, j++) {
            if (charArray[i] == charArray[j]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*This solution is terri-bad, but it works. Does not require additional data
      structures.
      Time complexity: O(n^2)
      Space complexity: O(1)/O(n).
     */
    public boolean worseSolution(String s) {
        if (s.length() > 256) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

So let's break down these methods.

The first method checks to see that the characters in the string are all unique by using a `Set`.

The second method is my personal favorite. It uses bit-masking to ensure uniqueness. I think run-time efficiency vs. the first method is ~8x better, but they're still the same complexity and for most applications the difference is negligible.

The third method sorts the characters and compares each character to its neighbors.

The final method is a nested-loop search of the array. Terrible, but it works.

Comment: In the first method, for space complexity you have the same as for time complexity.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate that @Wadda_wadda